# Unable to set session variable with $_POST value

Tags: php

setting this variable gives an error;
I tried every possible way but I'm unable to debug :

```
 >1.  $_SESSION[clas = $_POST['clas']];   ERROR Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=',                     expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 51

 >2. $_SESSION['clas = $_POST['clas']'];  ERROR  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 51

 >3 $_SESSION['clas = $_POST[clas]'];   ERROR  Notice: Undefined index: clas = $_POST[clas] in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 51

 >4 $_SESSION[clas = $_POST[clas]];   ERROR  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 51
```

Please suggest me something.

Comment: These are simple syntax errors in your code Ravi, so I suggest you to first study the syntax. A good place to start from here is http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 5):

```
$_SESSION['clas'] = $_POST['clas'];
```

Comment: by using this i get this error;Notice: Undefined variable: clas in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 52

Comment: Your comments are amusing. By the way, if you found my answer most useful, please click the check box next to my answer to "accept" it, so that future users know that you found this answer most helpful. You should always do this when posting questions. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add a value to the session, this is the correct way to do it :

```
$_SESSION['clas'] = $_POST['clas'];
```

`$_SESSION` and `$_POST` are [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), you can follow the link to the documentation for more information !

In short : array indexes are either numerical or a string, in your case you must use single quotes to delimit the string ( `'` ). And if you want to assign a value to an array element, you must use the correct syntax which is demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['clas'] = $_POST['clas']; ?>
```